# C# List.Add overwrites previous objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to create a simple list of objects, but somehow on every foreach loop the previous records are overwritten by the new one loop the previous record is overwritten by the new record. So if there are 6 entries in realData, the list will have 6x the last record.

Do I somehow recreate the List instead of adding to it? Is there another alternative that I have overlooked to create a List?

My code is

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> OrderOverview()
    {
        var itemList = new List<OrderItemVM>();
        var realData = await _context.OrderItem.ToListAsync();
        var orderItemVM = new OrderItemVM();

        foreach (var item in realData)
        {
            orderItemVM.Id = item.Id;                
            orderItemVM.OrderId = item.OrderId;
            orderItemVM.OrderName = _context.Order.Find(item.OrderId).OrderName;                
            orderItemVM.ItemName = item.ItemName;

            itemList.Add(orderItemVM);
        }

        return View(itemList);
    }
```

Comment: if `OrderItemVM` is a `class` you are constantly modifying the same instance in your loop

Comment: You need to read up on how reference types work. You only have one object, referenced by `orderItemVM`, which you keep updating, and adding the same reference to the list multiple times. Luckily there's an easy fix, move the statement `var orderItemVM = new OrderItemVM();` into the loop, as the first statement.

Comment: Think of an object as a house, and the variable as a post-it containing the address of the house. You're adding the address to the house to the list multiple times, but you keep rearranging the furniture in the same house over and over.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Thanks Lasse. Stupid of me. I will follow your advice on the reading ;)

Comment: Well obviously you are just modifying previous objects.

Comment: I wouldn't say it is stupid. It's a learning excercise **everyone** dealing with reference types in .NET has to go through. Believe me, we've all been there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because you are inserting the same reference of `orderItemVM` to `itemList`.
Also, you can set a default size for `itemList` and boost performance.

```
var realData = await _context.OrderItem.ToListAsync();     
var itemList = new List<OrderItemVM>(realData.Count);
```

And for this task, you can use LINQ:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> OrderOverview()
    {
        var realData = await _context.OrderItem.ToListAsync();
        var itemList = realData.Select(item => new OrderItemVM
        {
            Id = item.Id,
            OrderId = item.OrderId,
            OrderName = _context.Order.Find(item.OrderId).OrderName,
            ItemName = item.ItemNam,
        }).ToList();

        return View(itemList);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the additional TopTip!

Answer (score 5):

You are modifying the previously added objects instead of adding a new one. You should do this.

```
foreach (var item in realData)
{
    OrderItemVM orderItemVM = new OrderItemVM ();
    orderItemVM.Id = item.Id;                
    orderItemVM.OrderId = item.OrderId;
    orderItemVM.OrderName = _context.Order.Find(item.OrderId).OrderName;                
    orderItemVM.ItemName = item.ItemName;

    itemList.Add(orderItemVM);
}
```

So, basically on each iteration you create a new empty object and then assign that values and add that in List.

Comment: Thanks Rao. I got the same answer from Lasse.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Lasse V. Karlsen I discovered the error. I moved the line `var OrderItemVM = new OrderItemVM` in the Foreach-loop. That solved it.